# ODATA Support for JSON data using java and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, olingo

We have requirement to create ODATA supported Rest API. We will have to use Java and Mysql for this purpose. Data will be in JSON format which is dynamically changing and not possible to define the exact fields.

I'm looking at libraries like Apache Olingo for this. Documentation doesn't have that much of information about JSON support. Any thoughts on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Olingo is supporting JSON. It has a serializer for mapping from JSON - `org.apache.olingo.server.core.serializer.json.ODataJsonSerializer`.

But I'm not sure what do you mean by *dynamically changing and not possible to define the exact fields*. Do you want to use [Open Types](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part1-protocol-complete.html#_Toc453752202) from OData? Unfortunately, I have no experience with them in Apacha Olingo.

Comment: HI @Mate Here what i meant was json data fields keep changing. I will have a look at that as well.